# Access app data on iCloud drive

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'm new to IOS development so this is probably a silly question that is easy to answer.

I have created an IOS App using Core Data and CloudKit.  It is successfully syncing with iCloud Drive running on IOS 8.1.1

The app is functioning, and iCloud is syncing the data with multiple devices correctly, but I would like to know how to use a web browser to locate the files that are stored remotely in my iCloud Drive account.

It is not located in the iCloud Drive folder with the data from other IOS applications on www.iCloud.com and although I can find the name of the datastore in the iCloud Container section of my Developer profile, I cannot see how to access it directly from a browser.

Is there a way that I can access the stored data externally to test it for security and also to monitor it's size?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can see it using the web interface. You might be able to use the iCloud browser in Xcode to see the files, but I don't think that works either.

The way I usually do it is to open Terminal, and cd into `~/Library/Mobile Documents`, and then into the container for your app. The iCloud data should be in there.

(Note you can't use Finder because it hides all data outside Documents.)

Comment: Thanks Drew.  Unfortunately that will only show me a) what is in the local store on my computer and b) only replicas of those file that appear in the web interface of iCloud Drive.  My app files aren't there possibly because I'm storing them in a different local store(?). I'm really just interested in seeing what is actually up on the iCloud Servers.

Comment: The reason that I could not see my app data in ~/Library/Mobile Documents was that iCloud Drive on my development machine had not been enabled.  After enabling I was able to see the data on my local machine (still not in the cloud).  I also found that after enabling iCloud Drive, going into Preferences>iCloud and clicking 'Manage...' allowed me to see the size of my app data.  I still would like to know how to get to it while it is in the cloud, or know that it is impossible to do so.